# File Upload working on IE but not on Chrome and Mozilla

Tags: jsp, servlets, file-upload

I am trying to copy a file from one drive to another as we do on a webpage. I am using jsp-servlet combo for this. And for copying the file, i have used FileChannel.
This is working fine on the Eclipse's inbuilt browser and IE, but not on Chrome or Mozilla. Any suggestions ??

### Index.jsp

```
form action="Upload">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type ="file" name="file"></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="UPLOAD"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

### Upload.java

```
File f = new File(request.getParameter("file").toString());

        FileChannel ic = null;
        FileChannel oc = null;

        try
        {
            ic = new FileInputStream(request.getParameter("file").toString()).getChannel();
            oc = new FileOutputStream("e:\\"+f.getName()).getChannel();
            oc.transferFrom(ic, 0, ic.size());
        }
        finally
        {
            ic.close();
            oc.close();
        }
```

### Console on Eclipse :

```
Apr 01, 2014 5:18:00 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [util.Upload] in context with path [/FileUpload] threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at util.Upload.doGet(Upload.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:306)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:550)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:380)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:243)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:188)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:288)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: To actually upload a file, you would need `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on your `form` element. Looks though as if you don’t want to upload the file, but just want to get the file name (/path) – but how browsers have to handle that, if the mentioned enctype is not set, is not specified AFAIK. (And also modern browsers will _not_ give you the full local file system path anyway, for security reasons.)

Comment: You can't use `request.getParameter` with file uploads. Lookup Apache Commons File Upload.